# Amira L'Akum not on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, amira-leakum

One may not ask a non-Jew to do an action on behalf of the Jew if the action is assur on Shabbat (a gross over simplification, I know). This would constitute [Amira](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/19022/amira-lakum-say-you-cant-say) L'Akum (or Nochri).

Is there a parallel problem with asking a non-Jew to do an action which is assur to a Jew at any other time. I'm having trouble coming up with a quick example but, if a Jewish is not allowed to touch a woman who is not his wife, or embarrass someone, or yake mixed animals together, may he ask a non-Jew to do so for him? [better examples requested] Or is amira L'Akum limited to issuring based in the m'lachot of Shabbat?

Comment: This is actually a question the Talmud itself asks. See BM 90a. SA CM 338. We pasken that Amira Leakum applies even to other issurim.

Comment: @Bach I'm not really following where a problem would exist. If something is forbidden for a Jew but not for a Gentile, how could there be any prohibition involved?

Comment: @DanF - Exactly like Shabbos. It is prohibited to ask a gentile to perform something prohibited *on your behalf*, even if it is something he is permitted to do on his own.

Comment: @DanF This is Issur Gavrah, meaning we suspect that a person might disrespect the prohibition and start doing it himself. There's no *real* prohibition (Heftzah) as you rightfully noted.

Comment: As the answers say, it's forbidden. But, a fellow Jew only has to keep Shabbos on their Shabbos. So, if you start Shabbos early, you can ask a Jew to turn on the air-conditioner, but not a non-Jew.

Comment: Also, what about when traveling? Can you ask a non-Jew to turn off the lights before sundown on Friday where he and your house are, if it will be Shabbos already for you? The implication of my previous comment might be that you can't. That another Jew has his own Shabbos to keep or break, but the non-Jew's action is part of your keeping or breaking your Shabbos.

Comment: @Micha Berger - “ But, a fellow Jew only has to keep Shabbos on their Shabbos. So, if you start Shabbos early, you can ask a Jew to turn on the air-conditioner, but not a non-Jew” —— do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Draizy-LeviPine Arukh haShulchan OC 263:26. The SA itself raises the question in se'if 17, but leaves at as two opinions. We rule leniently, which is what you'll see in contemporary sources as well. (It's just that AhS Yomi is now in siman 267, so I remembered about where to look for that source.)

Comment: I believe the MB earlier clearly states otherwise that it is Mutar to ask a non Jew. The only issue comes up if it’s during bein hashmashos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Gemara (Baba Metziah 90a) discusses this:

> איבעיא להו: מהו שיאמר אדם לנכרי חסום פרתי ודוש בה, מי אמרינן: כי
> אמרינן אמירה לנכרי שבות - הני מילי לענין שבת, דאיסור סקילה, אבל חסימה
> דאיסור לאו - לא. או דלמא לא שנא

There is a dispute in the Rishonim how to *pasken*.

The Rambam ([Sechirus 13.3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=13&hilchos=74&perek=13&halocha=3&hilite=)) *paskens* it is forbidden.

> **אמר לעכו"ם חסום פרתי ודוש בה**. ישב לה קוץ בפיה ודש בה והרי אינה אוכלת.
> הרביץ לה ארי מבחוץ או שהרביץ בנה מבחוץ. הרי שצמאה ואינו משקה אותה. פרס
> עור ע"ג הדייש כדי שלא תאכל. **כל זה וכיוצא בו אסור** ואינו לוקה

This is also his position in *Hilchos Issurei Biah* ([17:13](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=27&perek=16&halocha=13&hilite=)):

> אסור לומר לעכו"ם לסרס בהמה שלנו ואם לקחה הוא מעצמו וסרסה מותר.

The *Maggid Mishna* cites the opposing view - seeing as the Gemara has a *safek*, and the halacha is that by a *safek d'rabbanan* we are always lenient, that it is permitted:

> אמר לעכו"ם חסום פרתי ודוש בה. **זו בעיא דלא איפשיטא בגמרא** ואתיא למיפשטה
> מאותה ברייתא דעכו"ם הדש בפרתו של ישראל דמדקאמר אינו עובר מכלל דאיסורא
> איכא ודחינן לה ורש"י ז"ל הלך לשיטתו ופירש ודוש בה דישתך והקשו עליו
> דבדישת העכו"ם מותר גמור הוא שאין איסור אמירה לעכו"ם אלא במלאכת ישראל
> אבל במלאכת העכו"ם מותר הוא דומיא דשבת שאפילו בשבת מותר לישראל לומר
> לעכו"ם לעשות מלאכת העכו"ם עצמו אלא ודוש בה דישתי קאמר **וקא מיבעיא לן כי
> אמרינן אמירה לעכו"ם שבות ה"מ שבת דאיסור סקילה אבל חסימה דאיסור לאו לא
> או דילמא לא שנא כדאיתא בגמרא ופסק רבינו דאסור וכן דעת הרמב"ן ז"ל
> דבכולהו מצות איכא שבות באמירה לעכו"ם**
> **ויש חולקין** ויש נוסחאות חלוקות ג"כ בספרי רבינו שבקצתן כתוב אומר לעכו"ם חסום פרתי ודוש בה משום **דכיון דבעיין לא איפשיטא אזלינן בה לקולא לפי שאיסור האמירה אפילו בשבת אינה אלא מדבריהם והו"ל ספיקא בדרבנן ולקולא** ומ"מ הנוסחא האמיתית בספרי רבינו אמר לעכו"ם **וכן הוא מוכרח ממ"ש פי"ז מהלכות איסורי ביאה** שאסור לומר לעכו"ם לסרס בהמה של ישראל ומוכיח בסוגיית הגמרא דלדידן דקי"ל דבן נח אינו מצווה על הסירוס אחד סירוס ואחד שאר מצות שיש בהן לאו האמירה לעכו"ם שוה בהו

The Shulchan Aruch ([338:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.338.6?lang=he)) paskens that it is forbidden:

> אמר לעכו"ם חסום פרתי ודוש בה (**דאמירה לעכו"ם אסור בכל איסורין כמו בשבת**)
> (טור בשם הרא"ש ורש"י והמגיד סוף הלכות שכירות) ישב לה קוץ בפיה ודש בה
> והרי אינה אוכלת רבץ לה ארי מבחוץ הרביץ בנה מבחוץ הרי שצמאה ואינו משקה
> אותה פירש עור על הדיש כדי שלא תאכל כל זה וכיוצא בזה אסור ואינו לוקה:

The Vilna Gaon (Biur Hagra 338:6) explains that the Gemara did actually reach a conclusion, forbidden asking a gentile to perform a prohibited act on your behalf. [And therefore is no longer a *safek drabbanan*.]

> אמר כו' דאמירה כו'. בעיא דאיפשיטא שם ת"ש דשלחו כו' ואף על גב דדחי ר"פ
> דיחוייא הוא דהא לא ק"ל כר' חידקא דהא פליגי עליה בסנהדרין שם ופשיטא
> דאביי ורבא ורב אחי ורב אשי ומרימר ומ"ז כולהו לא ס"ל כיחידאה. רא"ש וכלל
> כל הני יחד משום דאסור ואינו לוקה כמו בהנך דלא איפשיטא

[See however, the Rambam ([Kilayim 1:3](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=34&perek=1&halocha=3&hilite=)) who seems to hold it is permitted, in contradiction to his aformentioned view. The Raavad there disagrees, based on this Gemara - and he is clear it is still inconclusive, and nevertheless he rules to be stringent.

> ומותר לומר לנכרי לזרוע לו כלאי זרעים **- רמב״ם**
>
> ועוד אמירה לנכרי באיסור לאו בעיא ולא איפשיטא ולחומרא בבבא מציעא **- ראב״ד**

The answer to the contradiction in the Rambam is beyond the scope of this answer; I'm just bringing out that the Raavad has a stringent view even though it is a *safek drabbanan*, unlike the Vilna Gaon who rules that the stringency is a *vadai*.]

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Aruch (338:6) rules that it is forbidden.

> דאמירה לעכו"ם אסור בכל איסורין כמו בשבת

However, it is important to note that the exact parameters will be different to that of Shabbos. Regarding Shabbos, there are other prohibitions often mixed together with *amirah lakum*, which are of a different origin and therefore would not apply by other *issurim*.

For example, it is forbidden to tell a gentile on Shabbos to perform a *melacha* after Shabbos, although when he will actually perform the action it would be permitted to both the gentile and the Jew. Although this is colloquially referred to as *amirah lakum* and lumped together with the general prohibition of asking a gentile to perform a *melacha*, it is actually a spin-off of a different prohibition - *ve'daber davar*; one may not talk about prohibited actions on Shabbos.

This is specific to Shabbos. When it comes to other *melachos*, the prohibition is only the יש שליח לדבר עבירה לעכו״מ מדרבנן - that Chazal forbade asking a gentile to do something prohibited on your behalf. As long as at the time of execution, it is permitted, it wouldn't matter when you said it.

The same is true regarding *neheneh mi'maaseh shabbos*; there are instances where the *requesting* itself is permitted, but only forbidden because although it isn't *amirah lakum*, it is *maaseh shabbos* (a related, but different prohibition).

Comment: Sourcing your claims would improve your answer.